# Merge of [haystack] and [django-haystack] tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I propose a merge of the two tags [haystack](/questions/tagged/haystack) and [django-haystack](/questions/tagged/django-haystack).

Haystack is a Django app as is so there is little need for having two tags.
The description of "haystack" could be merged into the [django-haystack](/questions/tagged/django-haystack) tag.

I suggest that we keep the prefix `django-` as we do with [django-south](/questions/tagged/django-south)

To avoid confusion with double tagging much like [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917478/failed-to-query-solr-using-errno-111-connection-refused)

Comment: I will try and revive this question as it's still a problem where I have to retag up to 10 questions each week.

Answer (score 1):

I have retagged all Django Haystack questions that were tagged with [haystack](/questions/tagged/haystack), to [django-haystack](/questions/tagged/django-haystack).

There were 204 questions tagged [haystack](/questions/tagged/haystack), and there are now 23 remaining - all relating to generic *needle in a haystack* problems (mostly in PHP).

I have edited the tag wiki for [haystack](/questions/tagged/haystack) to mean the generic haystack problem:

> A haystack is a generic term for a set of results to search. For Django Haystack-related questions, use [django-haystack](/questions/tagged/django-haystack) instead.

Comment: But that's really not helpful. We shouldn't have two haystack related tags just as we don't have two [south] tags.

Comment: @limelights I don't understand why this isn't helpful... there will be only 1 Django Haystack tag. I'm about half way through this.

Comment: It won't keep people from still doing the tagging with Haystack since the module itself is called Haystack. People are seldom referring to the "haystack in a needle" type scenario or perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: If people use the wrong tag, that can't be helped. Hopefully the tag wiki edit I made will reduce this though. There are only 23 non-Django questions in the [haystack] tag - if there's consensus to burninate it, I say "go for it"!